# I can't get Tor to work with Vista

Tags: windows, help

I downloaded Tor for Vista but when I click it the hourglass comes up for a moment and then goes away without opening the program. Any ideas on how to open it?

Comment: Which version of what exactly did you download and on which icon do you click? It would be to answer your question, if you describe a bit more in detail what you're doing. Thanks.

Comment: It is torbrowser-install-4.5.2_en-US.exe and is located on the desktop. If I try to open it the hourglass icon shows up for about 2 seconds and then goes away with no noticeable affect. Thanks.

Comment: if you are facing problems and/or don't really know what to do with Tor i strongly advise you to use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click installer>Properties>General>Unblock

If your Vista is anything like mine windows has blocked the installer out of "fears" that it might be unsafe.

I just had the same problem and facepalmed when I realised it was so simple.

This could be your problem or it might not.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason windows vista blocks installers like Tor and Utorrent.
All you need to do is right click it. 
Select "Properties"--> "Unblock" at the bottom right-->"apply"-->"okay"
Then you can run it!